# API Gateway lambda authorizer custom status code

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a question about API Gateway authorizers and lambda functions.

My scenario is the following: I have a resource in AWS API Gateway for which the authorization is enabled. The authorizer calls a lambda function which, if the user is not authorized, redirects the user to another URL.

So basically I would like to customize the authorizer to return a 302 rather than a 401/403/500 status code. Do you know if that is possible?

I know that having a lambda function in the integration phase of the gateway lets me customize the response. What about this particular scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change status code or headers through Lambda Authorizer, but you can do it through *Gateway Responses*.

1. Go to API Gateway
2. Select the API you want to change
3. On the left panel, select **Gateway Responses**
4. Select the Response you want to override (e.g. `UNAUTHORIZED`)
5. Click Edit on the right panel

You can now redefine the response status, headers and body as you like.

Full documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-gateway-response-using-the-console.html

Comment: Is there a similar thing of Gateway Responses in AWS API Gateway HTTP (not REST) API?
I search but can't find it.

Answer (score -1):

A Custom API Gateway Authorizer returns an IAM Policy to API Gateway allowing or denying access to resources.

[Custom API Gateway Authorizer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html)

You can customize the response when the client tries to get a token (login), but in the authorization flow the API Gateway calls the Lambda function, supplying the authorization token extracted from a specified request header, then the lambda function returns an IAM Policy.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification but I am afraid this does not answer my question. After reading the documentation my conclusion is that you can have 4 flows:
`1. Lambda function returns a policy with Effect: Allow -> which is translated into forwarding the request`
`2. Lambda function returns a policy with Effect: Deny -> translated into 403`
`3. Lambda function returns callback('Unauthorised') -> translated into 401`
`4. Default case callback('Error...') -> 500 InternalServerError.`
So there is no way to way to return a type of JSON which would be translated into custom error.

Comment: Thanks, @TheRock3t -  link to documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html#api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-token-lambda-function-create